# Degeneracy in 3 dimensional infinite well and Number of states between $E$ and $E + e$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, density-of-states

I was reading Statistical Mechanics by Mcquarrie and met a function that describes the number of states of a single particle that has equal of less energy than $E$ in a 3d infinite well. The book describes that function by defining the radius $R$ of 3-dimensional space spanned by quantum numbers $n(x)$, $n(y)$, and $n(z)$.

In our case quantum numbers are integers. What if quantum numbers take different values?
For ex such that:
n(x) = n(x-1) + 2 and n(0) = 1,  n(x) = 1,3,5,7...
n(y) = n(y-1) + 3 and n(0) = 1,  n(y) = 1,4,7,10...
while n(z) is same               n(z) = 1,2,3,4...

Can I use the function given in the book, and just multiply it by 1/6 (1/2 x 1/3 x 1/1 = 1/6) to get number of states function given my new quantum numbers?

[image: first picture]

[image: second picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The density of states depends not only on the allowable quantum numbers but also on how the energy depends on these quantum numbers.  Let's say for the sake of argument that the energy formula is still something like
$$
\epsilon = \frac{h^2}{8 m a^2} (n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2).
$$
If $n_x$ can take on the values $1, 3, 5,\dots$ we can define $n_x = 2m_x - 1$ where $m_x = 1, 2, 3, \dots$.  Similarly, we can define $m_y$ such that $n_y = 3 m_y - 2$;  then we have $m_y = 1, 2, 3 \dots$ as well.  In terms of these new quantum numbers, the energy is
$$
\epsilon = \frac{h^2}{8 m a^2} ((2m_x - 1)^2 + (3m_y - 2)^2 + n_z^2) \approx \frac{h^2}{8 m a^2} (4 m_x^2 + 9m_y^2 + n_z^2).
$$
(The last approximation is valid so long as we are concerned mostly with energy states far from the ground state, which is pretty much always the case in the type of situations where the density of states is needed.)

At this point you can proceed with the argument as given by McQuarrie.  The only difference is that now the states with energy $\leq \epsilon$ lie in an octant of an *ellipsoid* in $m_xm_yn_z$-space, whose principal axes are not all equal.  But you can still figure out the volume of this ellipsoid in terms of $\epsilon$ to find the function $\Phi(\epsilon)$, and then differentiate $\Phi$ to find the density of states function.

Comment: Thank you! I would try to derive the new equation using the proper approach you gave. I wouldn't think of this ellipsoid space even if I come up with a proper Energy dependence idea and equation, thank you.